# EF Core - How to allow multiple cascade paths for foreign key deletion

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database in SQL Server 2019, with 4 tables. 1 for users, 1 for contacts, 1 for messages, and the last table that contains joined relationships between contacts and messages. (See image)

[image: MSPaint relationship]

Contacts and Messages are linked to the user via a foreign key, so when the user gets deleted, it would cascade the deletion of contacts and messages.

Messages can have multiple contacts linked, but not all contacts will be linked to a message.

A message may have no contacts at all.

I now need a foreign key that would delete the relevant records in the `MessageContacts` table when a contact gets deleted, as well as when a message gets deleted.

(Please note that this is just a demo scenario I set up to explain my problem)

Creating this scenario in Entity Framework Core, does not work, and gives me the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_MessageContacts_Messages_messageId' on table 'MessageContacts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Please see the configuration of my DbContext below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("AppUser");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Messages");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
            entity.HasOne<AppUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.userId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Contacts");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id);
            entity.HasOne<AppUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.userId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MessageContact>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("MessageContacts");
            entity.HasKey(e =>new {e.messageId,e.contactId });
            //Removing one of the below prevents my error, but then cascading deletions don't work
            entity.HasOne<Message>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.messageId);
            entity.HasOne<Contact>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.contactId);
        });
}
```

Removing the FK from `MessageContacts` for either `Contacts` or `Messages` prevents the error, but then the delete cascading does not work correctly. IE. Removing the FK on `MessageContacts` to `Messages` means that deleting a message, will not delete related records in `MessageContacts` leaving me with orphans.

Note: I have implicitly set the `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` option and it did not solve my problem either.

So I guess my question is, how do I accomplish this without the ability to define multiple cascade paths?

I would like to avoid doing anything manually in the database, so have everything done via EF Core migrations (if possible).

Maybe the entire model above is flawed, and someone has a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you can, it is a limitation by SQL server that it does not allow FK cascade chains like `A -> B` and `A -> C -> B`. The best you can do is set `DeleteBehavior` to `NoAction` in order to avoid the error SQL server will generate otherwise.

Comment: And there's no alternative to achieving this in Sql Server?
It works perfectly in MySql and MariaDB (Both of which are free), and it would suck to learn that our paid-for Sql environment cannot even do that.
Having to record the identities of records to be deleted, just for the sake of cleaning up my orphans, is really silly don't you think?

Comment: @Anomaly This is question/feature request for SqlServer. AFAIK it has been requested many times, but they decline to implement it.

Comment: This is not a sql server issue.  It is c#.  In SQL Server is you remove a row from a table it gets removed.  The link may not get removed.  for example if you have a table with Message IDs and the Table of messages.  If you remove all John Smith Messages some of the Messages in the ID table will point to null messages.  In c# class object do not get removed unless all links to the object are also removed.  So in c# when you remove all the John Smith messages the row will not be removed unless you also remove from the message ID table.

Comment: @jdweng Not sure what you mean. But it's a SQL Server issue. Nothing will ever "point to null messages". The foreign keys aren't nullable (and shouldn't be).

Comment: @GertArnold : You can have an ID in one table and the ID doesn't have to be in a 2nd table with same foreign key.   SQL Server doesn't do any checking if the foreign key exists.

Comment: @jdweng It is NOT a C# limitation, it is a Sql Server limitation. It works perfectly fine in MySql and MariaDB. The issue you seem to be describing sounds like there aren't any foreign keys to begin with.

Comment: We are saying the same thing.  There are different types of Database Architectures which handle linking of tables differently.  SQL Server doesn't have real linking so you have to JOIN tables by a common Key.  So in SQL Server when you remove a KEY you have to remove from all tables that use the key, otherwise, the key can be in one table and not another table.

Comment: @jdweng What are you talking about? First you said it is a C# issue. Now you are claiming SQL Server doesn't have real linking? The issue with SQL server is that it does not support cascading deletes fully compared to other options. Period. Also, last I checked SQL server is fully capable of enforcing relational integrity for FKs when it comes to inserting or updating data in the child table.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: I standby everything I said.  SQL Server does not have any linking.  Any combining of tables is done with JOINS.  And since there are no links, deleting from one table can leave hanging keys in other tables.

Comment: @jdweng Relational model is based on cartesian product, FKs and joins. I am trying to understand what other options there are that SQL server could support?

Comment: @TanveerBadar : I said issue is due to the architecture of SQL Server because it does not have true links so you can end up with hanging keys with that are not being used.  The handing keys may create errors because they return nulls which forces you to do extra testing for the nulls.  There are no options with SQL Server so except to remove the hanging keys by writing more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Microsoft's SQL Server and there's no way to get around it, unless you're willing to forget about cascading deletions via foreign keys, and instead, record the `Id` of the record you want to delete, then use it to manually remove all related records. That way, you aren't left with a bunch of orphaned records.

This is a really terrible way to go about it. The worst part is that SQL Server is a paid-for RDBMS, but it doesn't allow you to do something, that you can do using a free RDBMS like MySql or MariaDB.

So my solution?

Goodbye Sql Server, hello MySql.
This solution is only as practical as a developer or administrator's ability to switch from one RDBMS to another. This may not be possible at all in certain production scenarios.
I wish I could provide a better answer, but I don't think there is one.